# I can access jquery from developer console but not from inside a component in angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-cli

I have a script bundle that already includes jquery amont other things. I just want to use it. When trying to us it from a component it fails saying `ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. But when I go to console type `$('body')` for example it works correctly. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

I forgot to mention of course that the top of the page includes this:
`declare var $ : any;`

This is an angular-cli project and the bundle is already included in .angular-cli.json

Comment: Include jquery reference in the top of the page before you render other scripts

Comment: Maybe you need to inject $ to your component.

Answer (score 1):

Install typings for jquery:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

In your component at the top include this:

```
declare const $: JQueryStatic;
```

And make sure your src/tsconfig.app.json file has such keys:

```
"typeRoots": [
   "../node_modules/@types"
 ],
 "types": [
   "jquery"
 ]
```

Comment: When doing this I get the following `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryStatic'.`

Answer (score 0):

Angular-cli builds the project with webpack under the hood.

Now webpack tree-shakes everything that is not imported and bundle the whole thing into an isolated scope, hence if you don't have any reference to jquery, than it won't be available to your units

So just do in your ts file:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

maybe you also need to add the jquery package via npm:

```
npm install -S jquery
```

That -S stands for --save

plnkr demo here : https://plnkr.co/edit/y272nspAjnHy2wsTqzdh?p=preview

---

#### Some food for thought :

I strongly suggest not to use JQuery in your Angular 2+ projects, natives like `querySelector` and `addEventListener` with angular's bindings make jQuery obsolete.